# AWK that reads up to the /

Tags: awk, filter

I have the following lines of text :

```
170311 005201 0433 DE(N) itemhandling itemAddBarCodeData: Barcode(1/1) <0157357069/OK> ##[ti=7672,
170311 005323 0433 DE(N) itemhandling itemAddBarCodeData: Barcode(1/1) </NOREAD> ##[ti=7672,
```

I have the following script :

```
grep "itemAddBarCodeData" %myItemHandling% | gawk -F "[<>]+" -v OFS=, "{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){if($i~/Barcode/){print substr($1,5,2)substr($1,3,2)substr($1,1,2),substr($1,8,6),$(i+1)}}}" > %myOutputPath%%myFilename%
```

What I need is a script that reads only the /NOREAD and the /OK so the output is like :

```
11-03-17,00:52:01,NOREAD
11-03-17,00:53:23,OK
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the required output of said script for the given input.

Comment: Is the second field of the required output ("00:00:01") a constant field? If not how is it calculated from the input?

Comment: Lars, the field ("00:00:01") is just a time field and I can get that OK currently

Answer (score 2):

You can use this following script:

**script.awk**

```
/\/[A-Z]+>/ { match($1"-"$2,/(..)(..)(..)-(..)(..)(..)/,ts) 
              dt=mktime( sprintf("20%s %s %s %s %s %s", 
                                 ts[1], ts[2], ts[3], 
                                 ts[4], ts[5], ts[6]) )
              dtd = strftime( "%d-%m-%y", dt )
              dts = strftime( "%H:%M:%S", dt )

              match ( $0, /\/[A-Z]+>/)   # set RSTART and RLENGTH
              print dtd, dts, substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
            }
```

Run it like this: `awk -v OFS=, -f script.awk yourfile`

The important part is the second `match` function call, which matches

- a string of capital letters `[A_Z]`
- preceded by a `/`
- followed by a `>`.

It should match the `OK` and `NOREAD` case and *not* the `Barcode(1/1)`.

The variables

- `RSTART` and
- `RLENGTH`

are set by the `match` function, we have to correct them by +1 and -2, because the match RE included `/` and `>`.

The first `match`, mktime, strftime and the `sprintf` function call are another way the format the date and time. The time functions are GNU AWK extensions.

Comment: HI Lars appreciate the quick response and answer, is there a way of doing this on a single line ? I have a series of other lines that run within a batch file, so trying to keep it structured.

Comment: Hi Lars, I created your scripts and it works perfectly, would line a line command if possible to save having to create seperate scripts.

Comment: @Fabby I changed my answer.

Comment: @Fabby of course you can put the content of the script as an argument to awk. I keep the script in the answer for better readability.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the scripts, trying to add this to a single line

Comment: `gawk -v OFS=, -f "/\//" "{ if( match ( $0, /\/[A-Z]+>/) ) {print substr($1,5,2) "-" substr($1,3,2) "-" substr($1,1,2),substr($2,1,2) ":" substr($2,3,2) ":" substr($2,5,2),substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)}}"`

Comment: Doesn't quite work like this but works via script.awk

Comment: @Fabby That it does not work with the commandline in your comment could be a quoting issue. Can you try to put the script part in single `'` qoutes? If you do not have a bash, I fear that you need to escape the double quotes inside the script somehow.

Comment: Lars if I run it through the script.awk like this

Comment: `/\// { if( match ( $0, /\/[A-Z]+>/) ) {print substr($1,5,2) "-" substr($1,3,2) "-" substr($1,1,2),substr($2,1,2) ":" substr($2,3,2) ":" substr($2,5,2),substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)}}`

Answer (score 2):

Complex ***gawk*** approach:

```
awk -F"[ />]" '{patsplit($1, a, /[0-9]{2}/); patsplit($2, b, /[0-9]{2}/); 
     printf("%s-%s-%s,%s:%s:%s,%s\n",a[3],a[2],a[1],b[1],b[2],b[3],$10)}' inpufile
```

The output:

```
11-03-17,00:52:01,OK
11-03-17,00:53:23,NOREAD
```

---

`-F"[ />]"` - "composite" field separator

> **patsplit(*string*, *array* [, *fieldpat* [, *steps* ] ])**
>
> Divide *string* into pieces defined by *fieldpat* and store the pieces in *array* and
> the separator strings in the *seps* array.

Comment: Hi Roman, don't seem to be able to get this going, I should have said I'm running this on a windows machine through a DOS batch file

Comment: It will print lines without a `/OK` or `/NOREAD` string. Mind there are `/` inside the the file like in the `Barcode(1/1)` part,

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pragmatic combination of `awk` and `sed` that is conceptually relatively simple:

On **Linux** and **BSD/macOS**:

```
awk -F'[ />]' -v OFS=, '/itemAddBarCodeData/ {print $1, $2, $10}' file |
  sed -E 's/^(..)(..)(..),(..)(..)(..)/\3-\2-\1,\4:\5:\6/'
```

On a **Windows** system, **invoked from `cmd.exe`**, different quoting and line continuation rules apply (assumes the presence of *ported* GNU utilities):

```
awk -F"[ />]" -v OFS=, "/itemAddBarCodeData/ {print $1, $2, $10}" file ^
 | sed -E "s/^(..)(..)(..),(..)(..)(..)/\3-\2-\1,\4:\5:\6/"
```

Note how:

- `"..."` strings rather than `'...'` strings must be used to protect the embedded content from interpretation by the shell
- Unlike with `"..."` on *Unix*, `$` has no special meaning to `cmd.exe`, so it can be used as-is.
- `^` as the *very last* character on a line serves as the *explicit* line-continuation character, and the line must be broken *before* the `|` (whereas on Unix a line ending in `|` is *implicitly* continued).
  This is only used for *readability* here; of course, you can place your command on a *single line*.

Answer (score 1):

Regular awk version:

```
awk '
  {
    d=$1$2
    gsub(/../,"& ",d)
    split(d,T)
    split($8,R,"[/>]")
    printf "%s-%s-%s,%s:%s:%s,%s\n",T[3],T[2],T[1],T[4],T[5],T[6],R[2]
  }
' file
```

---

With script in file:
script.awk:

```
{
  d=$1$2
  gsub(/../,"& ",d)
  split(d,T)
  split($8,R,"[/>]")
  printf "%s-%s-%s,%s:%s:%s,%s\n",T[3],T[2],T[1],T[4],T[5],T[6],R[2]
}

awk -f script.awk file
```

---

crammed on one line..

```
awk '{d=$1$2; gsub(/../,"& ",d); split(d,T); split($8,R,"[/>]"); printf "%s-%s-%s,%s:%s:%s,%s\n",T[3],T[2],T[1],T[4],T[5],T[6],R[2]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need grep when you're using awk. With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '/itemAddBarCodeData/{print gensub(/(..)(..)(..) (..)(..)(..).*\/([^>]+).*/,"\\3-\\2-\\1,\\4:\\5:\\6,\\7",1)}' file
11-03-17,00:52:01,OK
11-03-17,00:53:23,NOREAD
```

Comment: Thanks Ed appreciate your response

Comment: Ed, it doesn't seem to work with the ' I always have to use the " quotes to get gawk to work in Windows ?

Comment: The common advice for anyone using Windows is to save your awk script in a file and invoke as `awk -f script` instead of trying to specify it on the command line to avoid Windows nightmarish quoting rules. Or even better install cygwin and invoke awk from that.